# What is the point of hashing?

Tags: security, password, hashsum, base64

I was looking at my companies hashing implementation and I saw that the passwords for the root user are stored in base64 encoding. What is to stop anyone from simply copying the password and doing a base64 -d on it? Or for someone to do the same thing to any other base64 password?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which is why you use a one-way hash, preferably with some salt

Comment: Base64 is not hashing, base64 is something you might call "transport encoding", or "ascii armoring": making sure that all the characters used can be transmitted over a 7-bit transportation system (sometimes even copy-paste through the clipboard, as you note, or a simple `echo`).

It is highly likely that the password is not just base64-encoded, but the hash will be, because otherwise the hash of the password can usually contain any byte value, including ones that are not printable or form invalid UTF-8 sequences, which will make things difficult if somebody ever needs to look at them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hash isn't an encoding, it's a non-reversible mathematical transformation. You can't take a hash and reverse the calculation to find the original value: you can only try brute-forcing a hash by trying passwords and hashing them to see if the hash matches.

Passwords are typically stored as a base64-encoded, salted hash of the password. It's the hash part that makes the password unrecoverable (and the salt part means that pre-generated lists of hashes are useless). Ideally the hash itself uses a lengthy calculation, so that brute-forcing is more expensive (we don't care about the cost of hashing in the nominal case since you only need to run one hash to determine whether a user-supplied password is valid).

For more information, see [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Comment: so if you look in /etc/shadow those passwords would be hashed then? When you log in does the kernel then hash the password you use to login with and then match with the /etc/shadow passwords?

Comment: Yes, `/etc/shadow` stores salted and hashed passwords. When you log in, typically it's a PAM module which handles the password check, following the principle you describe. The kernel isn't involved.